# Enable MySQL Connector/J GAE/Maven

Tags: mysql, google-app-engine, google-cloud-sql

I try to follow the documentation here:

https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/cloud-sql/?csw=1#using_the_java_development_server

But when I added the tag :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<appengine-web-app xmlns="http://appengine.google.com/ns/1.0">
  ...
  <use-google-connector-j>true</use-google-connector-j>
</appengine-web-app>
```

I got the exception:

> [INFO] SEVERE: Received exception processing
>   C:\Users\jerome\git\vidaao_app_engine\Vidaao\target\vidaao-1.0-SNAPSHOT\WEB-INF/appengine-web.xml
>   [INFO] com.google.apphosting.utils.config.AppEngineConfigException:
>   Unrecognized element  [INFO]  at
>   com.google.apphosting.utils.config.AppEngineWebXmlProcessor.processSecondLevelNode(AppEngineWebXmlProcessor.java:161)
>   [INFO]    at
>   com.google.apphosting.utils.config.AppEngineWebXmlProcessor.processXml(AppEngineWebXmlProcessor.java:61)
>   [INFO]    at
>   com.google.apphosting.utils.config.AppEngineWebXmlReader.processXml(AppEngineWebXmlReader.java:119)
>   [INFO]    at
>   com.google.apphosting.utils.config.AppEngineWebXmlReader.readAppEngineWebXml(AppEngineWebXmlReader.java:70)
>   [INFO]    at
>   com.google.apphosting.utils.config.EarHelper.readWebModule(EarHelper.java:130)
>   [INFO]    at
>   com.google.appengine.tools.development.AbstractContainerService.loadAppEngineWebXml(AbstractContainerService.java:334)
>   [INFO]    at
>   com.google.appengine.tools.development.JettyContainerService.initContext(JettyContainerService.java:160)
>   [INFO]    at
>   com.google.appengine.tools.development.AbstractContainerService.startup(AbstractContainerService.java:227)
>   [INFO]    at
>   com.google.appengine.tools.development.DevAppServerImpl.start(DevAppServerImpl.java:157)
>   [INFO]    at
>   com.google.appengine.tools.development.DevAppServerMain$StartAction.apply(DevAppServerMain.java:333)
>   [INFO]    at
>   com.google.appengine.tools.util.Parser$ParseResult.applyArgs(Parser.java:48)
>   [INFO]    at
>   com.google.appengine.tools.development.DevAppServerMain.(DevAppServerMain.java:269)
>   [INFO]    at
>   com.google.appengine.tools.development.DevAppServerMain.main(DevAppServerMain.java:245)

Comment: Please try configuring the steps provided by me in this answer to configure Cloud SQL on local as well as on remote instance. 

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14516319/google-appengine-cloud-sql-issue-with-spring-hibernate/14521643#14521643

Comment: I use maven so the SDK is hosted in an Artifact no way to include the driver there. That is my problem. No way to use Maven + GAE + Google Cloud SQL yet looks like. I think it's a huge problem

Comment: You can also refer to this answer related to GAE + Maven + Cloud SQL http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9478831/error-with-maven-gae-plugin-google-cloud-sql

Comment: Did you manage to solve it yet? Maybe try google support?

Comment: @idan 2 years after :) No i never manage to solve this issue. Everything worked perfectly beside this. But this one issue stopped me from using Maven with GAE. Such a pain!

Comment: @Jerome Ansia I've managed to make it work.
First I followed the steps here [appengine with mySQL](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/appengine-cloudsql-native-mysql-jdbc-demo-java) then I fixed one issue at a time. First issue was old appengine version that didn't work with new Maven so I used the latest (1.9.18), then in order to run the `mvn appengine:deserver` i added the following dependency:
`<dependency>
      <groupId>com.google.appengine</groupId>
      <artifactId>appengine-endpoints</artifactId>
      <version>${appengine.target.version}</version>
    </dependency>`

Comment: @idan Thank you! Unfortunately I stopped working with GAE a few months ago. But if I get back to it, it is on my bucket list! ;)